# How can I display values of arraylist in toast?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-dialog

I'm displaying checkboxes in alertdialog. When user clicks OK, toast should come up like You've selected PHP, Java, JSON. Right now, its displaying IDs. How can I get values?

```
  Dialog dialog;
    final String[] items = {" Objective C", " JAVA", " JSON", " C#", "PHP"};
    final ArrayList itemsSelected = new ArrayList();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Languages you know : ");
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedItemId,
                                    boolean isSelected) {
                    if (isSelected) {
                        itemsSelected.add(selectedItemId);
                    } else if (itemsSelected.contains(selectedItemId)) {
                        itemsSelected.remove(Integer.valueOf(selectedItemId));
                    }
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Done!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //Your logic when OK button is clicked
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You've selected "+itemsSelected,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

[UPDATE] I found solution but it doesn't seem ideal. For now its working by adding following code.

```
String one="";
                    String two="";
                    String three="";
                    String four="";

                    String zero="";
                    if (s.contains("0" ))
                    {
                        zero="Obj C ";
                    }
                    if (s.contains("1"))
                    {
                        one="JAVA ";
                    } if (s.contains("2"))
                    {
                        two="JSON ";
                    } if (s.contains("3"))
                    {
                        three="C# ";
                    } if (s.contains("4"))
                    {
                        four="PHP ";
                    }
```

Comment: Id is just position in the array you used to populate the MuliChoiceDilaog! (Its items[id] here).

Comment: Please explain in details. I couldn't get it.

Comment: If you look at the contents of itemsSelected, they are the indices of the items[] that were selected.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code

```
new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedItemId,
                                    boolean isSelected) {
                    if (isSelected) {
                        **itemsSelected.add(selectedItemId);**
                    } else if (itemsSelected.contains(selectedItemId)) {
```

itemsSelected.add(selectedItemId) simply adds the id to your arraylist. You do not want the id added. Since you want the exact values added, You can simply use something like itemsSelected.add(items[selectedItemId]) since the items array contains what values you need to display.  When you have put your correct values in your arraylist, then you display your toast maybe using itemsSelected.toString() or something. You also need to handle all the other checks.